# Barcode scanner plugin for Phonegap (or other solution) to scan ID cards?

Tags: iphone, ios, cordova, barcode-scanner

Can the Barcode Scanner Phonegap plugin scan and recognize an Identity Card? Like a drivers license or even a business card?

I'm looking for a solution that can recognize an ID card (similar to the way a barcode is scanned) so that the image can be saved and later uploaded to a server via a REST API.

I'm currently seeking a solution for iOS only at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you ID card has a Barcode, then Yes.  I scan my Minnesota ID/DL card and it reads the Barcode fine.  Though, with any camera type Barcode scanner, you need good lights in order to scan it.

Comment: No, I mean the card itself, not a barcode. Similar to the way Lemon Wallet scans ID cards. Basically it takes a photo of it when it is in focus.

Comment: Then that would be No.  Barcode scanner only scan barcodes,qrcodes, etc..  Additional functionality requires custom development.